# Java Spring How to Join the same column twice

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm working on a small project where you can track your matches in a game.

I run into a problem with joins and relations.

There are two classes: Fighter and Result.

Fighter has an id and the name of the fighter.
Result has an id, a boolean that stores if you won or not and two fighters: your own and the one of the opponent.

So each Result needs to be connected with two Fighters.

As you can see in the Code below I tried something, but the problem is, that the entries do not save.

```
@Entity
public class Fighter {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="id")
public int id;
@Column(name="name")
public String name;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}


@Entity
public class Result {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_char_one", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public Fighter fighter_one;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_char_two", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public Fighter fighter_two;

    public Fighter getFighter_one() {
        return fighter_one;
    }

    public void setFighter_one(Fighter fighter_one) {
        this.fighter_one = fighter_one;
    }

    public Fighter getFighter_two() {
        return fighter_two;
    }

    public void setFighter_two(Fighter fighter_two) {
        this.fighter_two = fighter_two;
    }

    public boolean win;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public boolean isWin() {
        return win;
    }

    public void setWin(boolean win) {
        this.win = win;
    }

}
```

Do you guys see something that I'm doing wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: which database are you using ?

Comment: @MansiJoshi I use MySQL

Comment: ok,I think you have to apply  foreignKey concept.

Comment: You need to show you are "saving"? How it is "not saved"? No major issue in the OR Mapping part here (except the `referencedColumnName = "id"` seems redundant)